# Possible to customize camera and user photo library views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-camera

Maybe this is the wrong place for this (if so, please help guide me where I should ask this). Would it be possible (or even an acceptable iOS practice) to customize:

1. The screen that shows when a user takes a photo.
2. The screen that shows when a user accesses their photo library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both these screens are provided by the UIImagePickerController class. You can handily customize the screen to take a photo - there's even API for it. You would first set `showsCameraControls` to `NO` to prevent the controller from drawing its own controls, then set a value for the `cameraOverlayView` property to insert your own controls over the camera. Take a look at the [UIImagePickerController docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) for more.

By contrast, you should not customize the photo library picker - that's a more traditional navigation interface, and Apple hasn't exposed any extra API to customize how it appears. You could (of course) always start poking into the view hierarchy of the controller once it's onscreen, but I think that would be a little more startling to your users than customizing the camera, and is more prone to break if Apple changes the guts of UIImagePickerController.

Comment: What if I want to add a button like a leftBarButtonItem in photo library view?

Comment: As this answer mentions, you shouldn't customize the library view. There's not really API for it (unlike how there's API for the `cameraOverlayView` and friends). You might consider building your own photo picker controller using the lower-level Photos.framework API.